# Add area in Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I want to add area folder to my project. Where I must click to add it?
[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found it. Click Add>New Scaffolded Item. After click choose the MVC area from the menu.

Answer (score 6):

I found in visual studio 2019.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Adding area in Asp.Net MVC is as simple as

1. Right click on your MVC project.
   2.Add
   3.Area
   4.Enter the Name of Area and done.

[what advantages we get by adding area in the project](https://www.https://www.sharpencode.com/article/MVC/areas-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

1. **Add** > **New Scaffolded Item**. After click choose the **MVC area** from the menu.
2. Copy **_ViewStart.cshtml**, **_ViewImports.cshtml** files from **Views folder** to the **Views folder inside the newly created area**(folder).

[image]